# Is there a way to get the azure AD client secret prorammatically using azure username and password?

Tags: java, azure

I know this is hidden in azure but wondering if we can still get it through api maybe?

Comment: Do you try to retrieve an existing user secret?

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Then I fear no.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve an existing user secret (not using the Azure Portal, nor using any API). 
If you forget the credentials for a service principal, consider [resetting the credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#reset-credentials).

Comment: How about the clientid of AD App is it possible to retrieve using only username and password, by sdk or api? Been reading a lot of microsoft docu but haven't seen anything confirming this is possible or not.

Comment: Well the reason I'm trying to get these are because I want to authenticate using ApplicationTokenCredentials in management library. The management library asks inputs like clientid, tenant id/domain, client secret. So I am checking if I can get clientid,tenantid, and client secret programmatically thru sdk or api perhaps, using azure username/password, so I won't need to hardcode them or ask user to input them.

Comment: I am already ok with tenant domain name, since if the user input their username then I can just extract the domain name from it. And for client secret I think it's dead end so just leave it that way for now. So now my concern is getting the clientid programmaticaly.